# Run multiple pre-trained Tensorflow nets at the same time

Tags: python, tensorflow

What I would like to do is to run multiple pre-trained Tensorflow nets at the same time. Because the names of some variables inside each net can be the same, the common solution is to use a name scope when I create a net. However, the problem is that I have trained these models and save the trained variables inside several checkpoint files. After I use a name scope when I create the net, I cannot load variables from the checkpoint files.

For example, I have trained an AlexNet and I would like to compare two sets of variables, one set is from the epoch 10 (saved in the file epoch_10.ckpt) and another set is from the epoch 50 (saved in the file epoch_50.ckpt). Because these two are exactly the same net, the names of variables inside are identical. I can create two nets by using

```
with tf.name_scope("net1"):
    net1 = CreateAlexNet()
with tf.name_scope("net2"):
    net2 = CreateAlexNet()
```

However, I cannot load the trained variables from .ckpt files because when I trained this net, I did not use a name scope. Even though I can set the name scope to "net1" when I train the net, this prevents me from loading the variables for net2.

I have tried:

```
with tf.name_scope("net1"):
    mySaver.restore(sess, 'epoch_10.ckpt')
with tf.name_scope("net2"):
    mySaver.restore(sess, 'epoch_50.ckpt')
```

This does not work.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create different sessions that use separate graphs for each model:

```
# Build a graph containing `net1`.
with tf.Graph().as_default() as net1_graph:
  net1 = CreateAlexNet()
  saver1 = tf.train.Saver(...)
sess1 = tf.Session(graph=net1_graph)
saver1.restore(sess1, 'epoch_10.ckpt')

# Build a separate graph containing `net2`.
with tf.Graph().as_default() as net2_graph:
  net2 = CreateAlexNet()
  saver2 = tf.train.Saver(...)
sess2 = tf.Session(graph=net1_graph)
saver2.restore(sess2, 'epoch_50.ckpt')
```

---

If this doesn't work for some reason, and you have to use a single `tf.Session` (e.g. because you want to combine results from the two network in another TensorFlow computation), the best solution is to:

1. Create the different networks in name scopes as you are already doing, and
2. Create separate [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) instances for the two networks, with an additional argument to remap the variable names.

When [constructing](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.__init__) the savers, you can pass a dictionary as the `var_list` argument, mapping the names of the variables in the checkpoint (i.e. without the name scope prefix) to the `tf.Variable` objects you've created in each model.

You can build the `var_list` programmatically, and you should be able to do something like the following:

```
with tf.name_scope("net1"):
  net1 = CreateAlexNet()
with tf.name_scope("net2"):
  net2 = CreateAlexNet()

# Strip off the "net1/" prefix to get the names of the variables in the checkpoint.
net1_varlist = {v.name.lstrip("net1/"): v
                for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope="net1/")}
net1_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=net1_varlist)

# Strip off the "net2/" prefix to get the names of the variables in the checkpoint.
net2_varlist = {v.name.lstrip("net2/"): v
                for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope="net2/")}
net2_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=net2_varlist)

# ...
net1_saver.restore(sess, "epoch_10.ckpt")
net2_saver.restore(sess, "epoch_50.ckpt")
```

Comment: Stripping the prefix by using lstrip may cause incorrect results. Please use slicing instead. Other parts of the code work perfectly. Another question is that I found the name of a variable has a postfix like ":0", ":1". Do I need to get rid of this postfix before I store variables into a checkpoint file?

Comment: Anyone tried this answer? I'm running into issues with the `restore` function not doing anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607144/loading-two-models-from-saver-in-the-same-tensorflow-session

Comment: This should actually be `v.op.name` instead of `v.name`, as described in the [documentation for Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#restore).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem that bothered me a long time. I found a good solution here: [Loading two models from Saver in the same Tensorflow session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607144/loading-two-models-from-saver-in-the-same-tensorflow-session) and [TensorFlow checkpoint save and read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112202/tensorflow-checkpoint-save-and-read).

The default behavior for a `tf.train.Saver()` is to associate each variable with the name of the corresponding op. This means that each time you construct a `tf.train.Saver()`, it includes all of the variables for the previous calls. Therefore, you should create different graphs and run different sessions with them.