# Using tensorflow Object-detection on only 1 classes

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using tensorflow (object-detection) on my own dataset (drone recognition), also only 1 class named 'drone', after about 30000 steps trained, my result model can detect drone with very high accuracy, but I got a problem, I used ssd_inception_v2_coco model and its fine_tune_checkpoint on model zoo, right now sometimes in my real time detection, it detected human face as drone (very big different between 2 objects like that), I think because of the old checkpoint.
How can I prevent the detection of some object that have big different with my drone object, like human, dog, cat... Or can someone describe for me what problem here?
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Do you apply transfer learning with model ssd_inception_v2_coco ?

Comment: Yes, I used trained model of ssd_inception_v2_coco as the base checkpoint

Comment: I think you should collect more data and retrain, by the way, how many layers which you freeze?

Comment: Yep, thanks for your advice. I keep default of the ssd_inception_v2_coco config, so I think it have 6 layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you train an SSD for one class, it automatically creates another class called background. The background is trained using the regions of the training images that are not labeled as the desired classes (in your case, drone).

An easy way out is to add training samples that include images that have both drones and the things that you don't want to recognize as drones, in the same scene. Doing this and then increasing the number of epochs should improve the precision.

If you are doing an application where there are frequent occurences of some objects with drones, another possiblity is to actually train the network for those things too. This will increase your training workload, but improve the accuracy.

Some implementations of SSD have an option for hard negative mining of data, so that mistakes made during validation are specifically used with training. If you are familiar with the code, you might want to check if this is available.

Comment: Oh, my dataset have no human face or something like dog, cat. Thanks for advice, I will remake my dataset and retrain my model

Comment: Nice, I'm not sure my final result will prety good or not, but I re-test with my new dataset that contain background, its result much better than my old result. I think your guide will resolve my problem.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Feel free to drop a message or comment here if there is anything that I might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry for an irrelevant question, I want to detect multiple objects, but from multiple single class trained models, not from one model that contain multiple class, is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is possible. And it is good in applications where the desired objects keep changing. There can be implementations problems if you want to load many large networks to the GPU memory, but usually this approach results in smaller networks.

Comment: I've tried to load 2 graphs at one time, but it ran about 10 seconds and crash (on Mac), I think cause of my wrong load method in code, but that link on homepage go 404: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/programming-with-multiple-graphs
Could you help me how to load multiple graphs?

Comment: I haven't tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175945/run-multiple-pre-trained-tensorflow-nets-at-the-same-time#39176114 but will check myself and edit this comment.