# How to restore two tensorflow models in a script

Tags: tensorflow

I write two scripts which contain segmentation and classification separately. These two models are trained and I want to use them to do prediction. The input of classification is based on the output of segmentation. Such as

```
from model1 import segmentation
from model2 import classification

images = segmentation(img)
pred = classification(images)
```

The problem is these two sentences can run solely but cannot run in sequence. Some problem about `train.saver` will occur.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the error that happens with `train.Saver`?

Comment: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key conv1_2/filter not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key conv1_2/biases not found in checkpoint                                                         this conv1_2 is a layer in segmentation. But this error occurs in processing pred = classification(images).

Comment: I found an useful answer   http://stackoverflow.com/a/41646443/7675662