# restoring two Tensorflow models

Tags: tensorflow, save, restore

I have trained two separate Tensorflow models and would like to use them both in one Jupyter notebook. I am following the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607144/loading-two-models-from-saver-in-the-same-tensorflow-session). However, I would like to avoid using `with` statement as it obscures my understanding of what is happening. Here is my code and error messages:

```
meta_path_1 = r'.\NN state save\case_guessing-3.meta'
checkpoint_path_1 = r'.\NN state save'

meta_path_2 = r'.\NN state save\class_guessing-3.meta'
checkpoint_path_2 = r'.\NN state save'

new_all_saver_1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path_1)
new_all_saver_2 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path_2)

graph_1 = tf.Graph()
graph_2 = tf.Graph()

sess_1 = tf.Session(graph = graph_1)
sess_2 = tf.Session(graph = graph_2)

new_all_saver_1.restore(sess_1, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path_1))
new_all_saver_2.restore(sess_2, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path_2))

predict_tensor_1= graph_1.get_tensor_by_name('predictions:0')
predict_tensor_2= graph_2.get_tensor_by_name('predictions:0')

x_1=graph_1.get_tensor_by_name('input_placeholder:0')
x_2=graph_2.get_tensor_by_name('input_placeholder:0')

print(sess_1.run(tf.shape(x_1)))
print(sess_2.run(tf.shape(x_2)))
```

Here is error message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from .\TNC-Kaggle\Output\NN_1\NN state save\case_guessing-3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-9f8dfdc2cc26> in <module>()
     14 sess_2 = tf.Session(graph = graph_2)
     15 
---> 16 new_all_saver_1.restore(sess_1, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path_1))
     17 new_all_saver_2.restore(sess_2, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path_2))
     18 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1558     logging.info("Restoring parameters from %s", save_path)
   1559     sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
-> 1560              {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
   1561 
   1562   @staticmethod

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1051       raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
   1052     if self.graph.version == 0:
-> 1053       raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
   1054                          'graph before calling run().')
   1055 

RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

How can I fix it? I already re-read multiple times google docs on interaction between graph and session, but I am still unclear what is missing. Inserging `as_default()` as some places produced different errors (too many to reproduce here)

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because you create the graphs after importing your models. Your models are imported into the current default graph at that point. There might be more issues, but in the very least you need to change your code to:

```
meta_path_1 = r'.\NN state save\case_guessing-3.meta'
checkpoint_path_1 = r'.\NN state save'

meta_path_2 = r'.\NN state save\class_guessing-3.meta'
checkpoint_path_2 = r'.\NN state save'

# Create the graphs first
graph_1 = tf.Graph()
graph_2 = tf.Graph()

# Import models into corresponding graphs
new_all_saver_1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path_1, graph=graph_1)
new_all_saver_2 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path_2, graph=graph_2)

# The rest of your code
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had was wondering the similar case as you did.
And I found a good answer from a link, although this guy said it is 'imperfect solution', it perfectly worked for me.

[Loading two models from Saver in the same Tensorflow session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607144/loading-two-models-from-saver-in-the-same-tensorflow-session)

According to the link, I think your code should look like below:

```
graph_1 = tf.Graph()
graph_2 = tf.Graph()

new_all_saver_1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path_1)
new_all_saver_2 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path_2)



sess_1 = tf.Session(graph = graph_1)
sess_2 = tf.Session(graph = graph_2)

with sess_1.as_default():
    with graph_1.as_default():
        new_all_saver_1.restore(sess_1, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path_1))
with sess_2.as_default():
    with graph_2.as_default():
        new_all_saver_2.restore(sess_2, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path_2))

predict_tensor_1= graph_1.get_tensor_by_name('predictions:0')
predict_tensor_2= graph_2.get_tensor_by_name('predictions:0')
```

If it produces other error after you apply this, then you probably have to apply

```
with sess_n.as_default():
    with graph_n.as_default():
```

to your graph_1.get_tensor_by_name part....