# Inference using saved model in Tensorflow 2: how to control in/output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Adapting my code from TF1 to TF2.6 I run into trouble.
I am trying to add some custom layers to an inception resnet, save the model, and then load and run it.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2                                                                                 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D                                                                                               
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                                                         
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                              
from PIL import Image                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                
export_path = "./save_test"                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                
# Get model without top and add two layers                                                                                                                      
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, include_top=False)                                                                        
out = base_model.output                                                                                                                                         
out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out)                                                                                                                             
predictions = Dense(7, activation='softmax', name="output")(out)                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                
# Make new model using inputs from base model and custom outputs                                                                                                
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[predictions])                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                
# save model                                                                                                                                                    
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_path)                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                
# load model and run                                                                                                                                            
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:                                                                                                            
    tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], export_path)                                                                                          
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                
    img = Image.new('RGB', (299, 299))                                                                                                                          
    x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)                                                                                                          
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)                                                                                                                               
    x = x[..., :3]                                                                                                                                              
    x /= 255.0                                                                                                                                                  
    x = (x - 0.5) * 2.0                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                
    y_pred = sess.run('output/Softmax:0', feed_dict={'serving_default_input_1:0': x})
```

Error:
`KeyError: "The name 'output/Softmax:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'output/Softmax', does not exist in the graph."`

What I don't understand:
`predictions.name` is `'output/Softmax:0'`, but
`graph.get_tensor_by_name('output/Softmax:0')` tells me it does not exist!

**Note:** I am aware that I can save and load with TF2's `tf.keras.models.save` and `tf.keras.models.load_model` and then run the model with `model(x)`. However, in my application I have multiple models in memory and I have found that the inference takes much longer than in my TF1 code using the `session` object. I would therefore like to use the TF1 approach with the `session` object in compatibility mode.

How can I control the names of input/output when saving? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

### **Tested on TF 2.0, 2.6, and 2.7**:

If you haven't already, you could try something like the following, as I believe you are referencing the wrong keys in `SignatureDef`:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2                                                                                 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D                                                                                               
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                                                         
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                              
from PIL import Image                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                
export_path = "./save_test"                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, include_top=False)                                                                        
out = base_model.output                                                                                                                                         
out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out)                                                                                                                             
predictions = Dense(7, activation='softmax', name="output")(out)                                                                                                
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[predictions])                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                              
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_path)

with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:                                                                                                            
    meta_graph = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], export_path)
    sig_def = meta_graph.signature_def[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
    input_key = list(dict(sig_def.inputs).keys())[0]
    input_name = sig_def.inputs[input_key].name
    output_name = sig_def.outputs['output'].name
    img = Image.new('RGB', (299, 299))                                                                                                                          
    x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)                                                                                                          
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)                                                                                                                               
    x = x[..., :3]                                                                                                                                              
    x /= 255.0                                                                                                                                                  
    x = (x - 0.5) * 2.0   
    y_pred = sess.run(output_name, feed_dict={input_name: x})        
    print(y_pred)
```

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./save_test/variables/variables
[[0.14001141 0.13356228 0.14509581 0.22432518 0.16313255 0.11899492
  0.07487784]]
```

You could also take a look at the `SignatureDef` for input and output information:

```py
print(meta_graph.signature_def)
{'serving_default': inputs {
  key: "input_2"
  value {
    name: "serving_default_input_2:0"
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
outputs {
  key: "output"
  value {
    name: "StatefulPartitionedCall:0"
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 7
      }
    }
  }
}
method_name: "tensorflow/serving/predict"
, '__saved_model_init_op': outputs {
  key: "__saved_model_init_op"
  value {
    name: "NoOp"
    tensor_shape {
      unknown_rank: true
    }
  }
}
}
```

If you remove the first layer of your `base_model` and add a new `Input` layer, you can use static key names `sig_def.inputs['input'].name` and `sig_def.outputs['output'].name`:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2                                                                                 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D                                                                                               
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                                                         
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                              
from PIL import Image                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                
export_path = "./save_test"                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, include_top=False)
base_model.layers.pop(0)
new_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(299,299,3), name='input')
out = base_model(new_input)                                                                                                                                        
out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out)                                                                                                                             
predictions = Dense(7, activation='softmax', name="output")(out) 

model = Model(inputs=new_input, outputs=[predictions])                                                                                                   
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_path)

with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:                                                                                                            
    meta_graph = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], export_path)
    sig_def = meta_graph.signature_def[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
    input_name = sig_def.inputs['input'].name
    output_name = sig_def.outputs['output'].name
    img = Image.new('RGB', (299, 299))                                                                                                                          
    x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)                                                                                                          
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)                                                                                                                               
    x = x[..., :3]                                                                                                                                              
    x /= 255.0                                                                                                                                                  
    x = (x - 0.5) * 2.0   
    y_pred = sess.run(output_name, feed_dict={input_name: x})        
    print(y_pred)
```

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./save_test/variables/variables
[[0.21079363 0.10773096 0.07287834 0.06983061 0.10538215 0.09172108
  0.34166315]]
```

Note that changing the name of the first layer of `base_model` does not work with the syntax `model.layers[0]._name = 'input'` because the model configuration itself will not be updated.

Comment: Nice! `sig_def` seems to be the one I was searching for!!

Comment: Do you happen to know if I can load multiple models into one session this way? When doing this for example with `tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(meta_graph.graph_def, name="model1")` and then load another model, it looks like things get mixed up...

Comment: Have never tried it but I would like to think that you would need two sessions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607144/loading-two-models-from-saver-in-the-same-tensorflow-session